# QT5 eglfs on embedded linux (TI am355x evm starter kit)

Tags: linux, embedded, qt5

I’ve just cross-compiled QT 5.2.1 for ARM and I am using it on a TI AM335x EVM (Starter Kit) board.

I’de like to use the eglfs platform, but unluckily it shows some artifacts on the screen…

I just made a simple program for showing the problem and captured some photos of my screen. The program basically draws a set of vertical black and white lines (alternated).

If I run QT on platform linuxfb (that is I launch my program passing “-platform linuxfb” on command line) then the software works fine… Here is a photo of my screen:

[image]

If instead I run QT on platform eglfs (that is I launch my program passing “-platform eglfs” on command line) then I have some artifacts near the center of screen (it seems that some vertical lines are “missing” or “swapped”)… Here are two photos of my screen:

[image]

Any idea about that?

Furthermor it seems that on the same board QT 5.2.1 is slower than QT 4.8.x (using QWS)… how is it possible? Is there some optimization that can be turned on while compiling QT 5.x?

Comment: If you display an image full screen, or say just like a white box full screen do the lines remain?

Comment: Drawing a box full screen the problem is not there... but anyway I found a solution... see below! Thanks for your interest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, if found a solution. I was drawing within a QWidget… Drawing within a QGLWidget the problem is fixed.